# draw single pole double throw switch in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I am new to circuitikz so this question may be too easy for some of you. I want to draw a single pole double throw switch in circuitikz. It can be done with "spdt". However I don't find any example of using it in the manual. I just don't know how to connect this 3-terminal component with the surrounding ones. Can anyone provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. Then those trying to help can have something to start with.  Solving problems can be fun, but setting them up isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three anchors you are looking are `<name>.in`, `<name>.out 1`, and `<name>.out 2`. A little example showing a `spdt` component alone with its main three anchors, and another one showing how to connect some of these components with others; sorry if the examples lack any "real" meaning (I know nothing about circuits):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(1,0) node[spdt] (myspdt) {}
(0,0) -- (myspdt.in) 
(myspdt.out 1) -- +(1,0)
(myspdt.out 2) -- +(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(2,2) node[spdt] (myspdt1) {}
(2,0) node[spdt] (myspdt2) {}
(0,1) node[spdt] (myspdt3) {}
(5,1) node[and port] (myand) {}
(myspdt3.out 1) -| (myspdt1.in)
(myspdt3.out 2) -| (myspdt2.in)
(myspdt1.out 1) -- (myand.in 1)
(myspdt2.out 2) -- (myand.in 2)
;\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your example code. It is great to get started with. One small question: I saw you used "--", "-- +" or "-|" to connect two nodes. What is the difference among them?

Comment: @shva You're welcome! Regarding your questions, `(a) -- (b)` means a straight line from `(a)` to `(b)`; `(a) |- (b)` means a line from `(a)` to `(b)`, but first vertical and then horizontal (`-|` means first horizontal, then vertical). Now the plus signs: `+(0cm,1cm)` means "`1cm` upwards from the previous specified position" and `++(2cm,0cm)` means "`2cm` to the right of the previous specified position, making this the new specified position".